# How can i make button from one button make function from other class in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make that if i click tab button the content of this tab will change. In this specific example, I want to change TextInput to day that it is today. But I have no clue how to execute function from WoPlan class in Menu class. Or just how to influence the WoPlan textinput via menu's button from tab.

.kv

```
<Menu>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        ORM:
            font_size: 30
            text: "ORM"

        WoPlan:
            font_size:30
            text: "WOP"
            on_press: root.WoPlan().weekday()

<WoPlan>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: weekday
            disabled: True
```

.py

```
class WoPlan(TabbedPanelItem):

    def weekday(self):
            curr_date = date.today()
            weekday = calendar.day_name[curr_date.weekday()]
            self.ids.weekday.text = weekday

class Menu(Screen):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `root.WoPlan().weekday()`, you can write `self.weekday()`.
The "self" refers to the Widget, in which the `on_press` is called ("WoPlan" in this case).

If you want to call the function from any other widget within the "Menu" Screen, e.g.:

```
<Menu>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        ORM:
            font_size: 30
            text: "ORM"
        Button: #example widget
            on_release: root.ids["woplan"].weekday()

        WoPlan:
            id: woplan
            font_size:30
            text: "WOP"
```

Comment: I get this error:
on_press: root.ids["woplan"].weekday()
KeyError: 'WoPlan'
When i wrote this root.ids["woplan"]
The button that i want to press is in Menu Class, not in WoPlan.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can do that with `current_tab: self.weekday()`

I just needed to put it in here

```
<Menu>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        ORM:
            font_size: 30
            text: "ORM"

        WoPlan:
            font_size: 30
            text: "WOP"
            current_tab: self.weekday()
```